# SQL Error (1235): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql

I am getting the

```
 /* SQL Error (1235): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT 
& IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' */
```

The update query I writing is this

```
update id_card 
set division_category='678' 
where CODE  IN ( SELECT code  
                 FROM id_card 
                 WHERE CODE LIKE '%922846%' 
                 ORDER BY version DESC LIMIT 1
                 );
```

How to re-write this  ?

Comment: share your table structure

Comment: Would be better if you post table description some datas and expected result, not only for you but for all that might face same problem. So we could give a proper answer , not just guessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE id_card
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT code 
  FROM id_card 
  WHERE version LIKE '%922846%'
  ORDER BY version DESC
  LIMIT 1
) as t2 using (code)
SET division_category = '678' 
WHERE id_card.code = t2.code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try, but have to verify if the result is correct yourself:

```
update id_card 
set division_category='678' 
where CODE  IN (SELECT code  
                FROM id_card 
                WHERE CODE LIKE '%922846%' 
                  AND version = (SELECT MAX(version) 
                                 FROM id_card 
                                 WHERE CODE LIKE '%922846%' )
LIMIT 1;
```

EDIT: Added the `LIMIT 1`, because @Solarflare is right, without it you can update more than 1 record. But still care needs to be taken because  the `version = SELECt MAX(...` can result in more than 1 records, and you have to make sure (somehow) the correct record of those multiples is selected.

Comment: This will (in general) have a different effect than the original query (well, if the original query would work): if there are several codes with the same (max) version, this will update multiple codes, while the original subquery only returns and thus updates a single code (although it is possible that this is what the op actually wants to do).

Comment: @Solarflare: Added a `LIMIT 1` with some more explanation as a warning...

Comment: Adding Limit 1 to the update will also (in general) have a different effect: it will update a single row instead of all rows with the same code (e.g. version 1 of the code, but leaving version 2 of that code unmodified) . If code is unique, this may work though.